# RelativeLayout child shifting to right even after setting CenterHorizontal=true

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to create a Relative layout with View buttons at bottom and a sign in button on top of it. Problem is eventhough I have aligned the child to be center with respect to parent, it keeps shifting to right.

Here's the screenshot of the view.

[image]

And the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/screenOneFooter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4" >

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/one_view1"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circledarkstyle" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/one_view2"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlestyle_g1" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/one_view3"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlestyle_g1" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/one_view4"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlestyle_g1" />
            </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/screenOneFooter"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="#e86e6d"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/com_facebook_likebutton_compound_drawable_padding"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/com_facebook_inverse_icon"
                    android:gravity="top|bottom|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:onClick="onLoginClick"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/com_facebook_loginview_padding_bottom"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/com_facebook_loginview_padding_left"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/com_facebook_loginview_padding_right"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/com_facebook_loginview_padding_top"
                    android:text="@string/com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button"
                    android:textColor="@color/com_facebook_loginview_text_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/com_facebook_loginview_text_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

        

</RelativeLayout>
```

Dragging the button left towards the central dotted line doesn't have any effect. It shifts back.Any thoughts ?

## EDIT:

Till devices of screen size 4", layout child seems to be centered. After 4" (4.65" to be precise) and above screen sizea, its as shown in the above screenshot. Weird ? Am I missing something here ? –

Comment: Try android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" in button. I think attribute gravity has no effect on a relative layout. You've to align the child with respect to the parent.

Comment: It's centered when I copy your code. Maybe something in the styles.xml? Like a padding or margin on one side.

Comment: @gauravjain I guess `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" ` does the job of ` android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" `. Still no change !!

Comment: @InnekeDeClippel That's strange. What's even stranger is that the screenshot I posted was taken from a 4.7" WXGA. When I changed device to 3.2" QVGA, everything seems to be proper. So the problem is not with code ?

Comment: Are you using multiple layout directories or styles.xml files for different api levels or screen resolutions? If not, then I don't know what the problem might be. Maybe a bad device if it only occurs on the WXGA.

Comment: @InnekeDeClippel No I'm not using multiple layout directories or styles.xml. But things get more interesting now- Till devices of screen size 4" layout child seems to be centered. After 4" (4.65" to be precise), its as shown in the above screenshot for every screen size above. Weird ? Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/screenOneFooter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4" >

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/one_view1"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/one_view2"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/one_view3"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/one_view4"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:background="#e86e6d"
                    android:gravity="top|bottom|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:onClick="onLoginClick"
                    android:text="@string/hello_world"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just for your information, see the screenshot.[image]